# Spring boot 2.3.1 and Spring cloud gatewat 2.2.1 ; Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name CustomFilterName

Tags: java, spring-cloud-gateway

I created a custom filter with the name "CustomFilterName" below are my config and java files.

Error Received :

> reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find
> GatewayFilterFactory with name CustomFilterName Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find
> GatewayFilterFactory with name CustomFilterName
>
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.loadGatewayFilters(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:180)
> ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.getFilters(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:226)
> ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.convertToRoute(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:163)
> ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]  at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:704)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:580)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:970)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8325)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:418)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:267)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:225)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:363)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8325)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:418)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:267)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:225)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:363)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalFluxOperator.subscribe(InternalFluxOperator.java:62)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:54)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8325)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith(Flux.java:8494)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8295)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8222)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8140)
> ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter.lambda$onApplicationEvent$0(WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java:145)
> ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider.ifAvailable(ObjectProvider.java:93)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter.onApplicationEvent(WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java:145)
> ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteRefreshListener.reset(RouteRefreshListener.java:68)
> ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteRefreshListener.onApplicationEvent(RouteRefreshListener.java:49)
> ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:62)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
> [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
> [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
> [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
> [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
> [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
> [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]

CustomFilterName.java

```
@Component
public class CustomFilterName extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<CustomFilterName.Config> {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomFilterName.class);

    public static final String A_var = "thisIsA_Class";
    public static final String B_var = "thisIsB_Class";

    public CustomFilterName() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return new OrderedGatewayFilter((exchange, chain) -> {
            logger.info("Pre GatewayFilter logging: " + config.getA_var());
            return chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                logger.info("Post GatewayFilter logging: " + config.getB_var());
            }));
        }, 1);
    }

    public static class Config {

        private String A_var;
        private String B_var;

        public String getA_var() {
            return A_var;
        }

        public void setA_var(String a_var) {
            A_var = a_var;
        }

        public String getB_var() {
            return B_var;
        }

        public void setB_var(String b_var) {
            B_var = b_var;
        }

        public Config() {
        };

        public Config(String A_var, String B_var) {
            super();
            this.A_var = A_var;
            this.B_var = B_var;
        }

    }
}
```

app.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gs-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
     routes:
      - id: test_route
        uri: http://httpbin.org/
        predicates:
        - Path=/incoming/**
        filters:
        - AddRequestHeader=X-Y-Host, delta
        - name: CustomFilterName
          args:
            A_var: thisIsA_yml
            B_var: thisIsB_yml
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-cloud-gateway.version>2.2.1.RELEASE</spring-cloud-gateway.version>


<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-gateway.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, I had to clean my M2 repo folder by deleting all the old dependencies. And did a fresh Maven Force Update. The above mentioned error is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I had to clean my M2 repo folder by deleting all the old dependencies in repo folder. And did a fresh Maven Force Update. The above mentioned error is gone.